# Opening a web page after connecting on an WiFi (mobile)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

There is a way to force the mobile device to opening an web page after connect on an WiFi?

This is not about a HotSpot (web authentication).

**Example:** after connecting on an WiFi, the default browser opens automatically on the device and redirect to a predetermined URL.

This is possible?

**Edit:** on every mobile OS (Android, iOS, WP and BB).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a built-in feature in most captive portal solutions. Most phones today have a client implementation for this too. For example, on an Android a notification can be displayed, asking the user to connect to the network. On iPhone, usually it opens the browser right away.

The web front you can have on a hotspot connection is handled by a captive portal, but that doesn't mean authentication is a must-have. It's simply not reasonable in most cases to not have authentication on your network. Note that it's also possible to handle authentication on a lesser level.